# (Android recovery) how to let /cache/recovery/command execute more orders?

Tags: android, recovery

I want to install zip from sdcard by recovery  and I write a file named command :

```
--update_package=/sdcard/my-rom.zip
```

put the file into `/cache/recovery`  then  run

```
*adb reboot recovery*
```

It works.

but if not  wipe_data ,there are problems about android system sometimes.
so I write the code into command file.

```
--wipe_data

--update_package=/sdcard/my-rom.zip
```

it is not working only run the last command ,not wipe_data.

How can I let the command execute by order?

Comment: Some counter-questions: 1) Does "--wipe-data" work on its own? 2) Have you tried removing the empty line between the two commands?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

-> cache/recovery/openrecoveryscript

> wipe data
>
> install /sdcard/my-rom.zip